# How many words fit in 4 bits

Tags: numbers, byte, bit

I have 2 questions that I would like to get helped with.

**First question is:** If you have 4 bits, how many unique numbers can you write?

**Second question is:** If you have 4 bits, what is the largest number you can write. Answer with the base 10

Appreciate any help!

Edited - nothing really

Comment: If youre going to downvote, atleast tell me why

Comment: It looks like your asking for people to do your homework. Have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary

Comment: If you show what you have worked on and where you are stuck you might get more help.

Comment: Its not about asking people to do my homework, this is the actual question which is either know it or not, and I didnt, thats why I needed an explaination which I got from the gents below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1)**    With the `4` bits we can write `16` different numbers. As we have `4` different position of bits let's say `ABCD` where `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` are representing `1` bit. Each position `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` has two possible input `0` or `1` so each position is having `2` possible inputs.

So for `4` positions total different outputs = `2*2*2*2` =`16` Which also can be understood by `permutation` which is equal to `2^(no.of bits)` .Here `2^(4)` which is equal to `16`.

**Answer 2)**  Mamimum number having `n` bits is always all bits as `1`s so for `n` bit number, maximum number which can be formed is all `n` `1`s.

So for `4` bit number, Maximum number which can be formed is `4` `1`s in binary representation of the number. So here that number is `1111` in binary . In decimal it is `15`.

It also can be calculated by `2^(no.of bits) -1`. Here number of bits is `4` so maximum number is `2^(4) -1` which is `16-1`= `15`

Comment: Thank you very much mate for the answer, this was very detailed and made me understand how to calculate these things in the future and actually made me understand it perfectly. Thanks again and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Is this your college assignment or sth?

The answer is simply,

if you have n bits, you can have 2^n unique numbers.

The largest number you can write is n 1's.

i.e. For four bits,

Number of unique numbers  = 2^4 = 16

The largest number = 4 1's  = 1111 = F (hex) = 15 (Base 10)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help mate, and yes it is! Wish you the best!